# NaturalDocs source code not building in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, documentation, documentation-generation

I cannot get NaturalDocs to compile. It is unaltered code cloned from the official NaturalDocs repo (https://github.com/NaturalDocs/NaturalDocs).

I'm getting the following errors:

---

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Engine, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>C:\dev\NaturalDocs\Engine\Source\Languages\Parsers\SQL.cs(911,45,911,51): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'string'
1>C:\dev\NaturalDocs\Engine\Source\Languages\Parsers\SQL.cs(911,52,911,66): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CLI, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\dev\NaturalDocs\Engine\bin\Debug\NaturalDocs.Engine.dll' could not be found
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I made sure that the project build dependencies are in the correct order, but it seems the **Engine** project can't build.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with syntax that was not compatible with the C# version in VS 2015. This issue doesn't occur in VS 2017 and VS 2019. The developer of NaturalDocs fixed this issue so it should be compatible with VS 2015: ([NaturalDocs GitHub issue](http://github.com/NaturalDocs/NaturalDocs/issues/4)). Thanks.